# PHP AWS SDK Change_content_type not successful

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to change the content type of a file after is had been uploaded to AWS, from it's default to an image/jpeg. I am using the [Amazon Web Service Bundle](https://github.com/Cybernox/AmazonWebServicesBundle) in my symfony2 project. I got this code snippet from [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=s3browserupload/change_content_type).

```
        $bucket = $awsConnectionParams['aws_s3_bucket'];

        $s3 = $this->container->get('aws_s3');
        $cct = $s3->change_content_type($bucket, $filePath, 'image/jpeg');
        sleep(5);
        $metadata = $s3->get_object_metadata($bucket, $filePath);

        // Success?
        var_dump($cct->isOK());
        var_dump($metadata['ContentType']);
        die;
```

The output is:
bool(false)
NULL

The file path is correct as I use it to construct a "read file" url later on, with my poor image as a forced download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By outputting the response body:

```
var_dump($cct->body);
```

I was able to see the actual failure message which was

```
Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.
```

I had to trim a "/" off my file path for it to authenticate, the following worked.

```
    $filePath = ltrim($filePath, '/');

    $s3 = $this->container->get('aws_s3');
    $s3->change_content_type($bucket, $filePath, 'image/jpeg');
```